# How to scrape this links with follow_link in R?

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm learning how to do web scraping with R. In this case i'm using the package "rvest" and a particular function called follow_link.

The idea is to get the information of a webpage that has multiple links. I want my code to enter in those links and get the table that is in it.

This is the code:

```
library(rvest)
s <- html_session("http://fccee.uvigo.es/es/profesorado.html")
link <- c("Dereito Privado", "Economia Financieira e Contabilidade", "Matemáticas",
      "Estadística e Investigación Operativa", "Economía Aplicada", "Fundamentos da Análise Ec. e Hª e Institucións Económicas",
      "Informática", "Organización de Empresas e Marketing", "Socioloxía, Ciencia Política e da Administración e Filosofía")
n <- length(link) #number of pages
datos <- list()
for (i in 1:n){

    s <- s %>% follow_link(link[i])
    datos[[(i)]] <- s %>% html_nodes(".lista_fccee") %>% html_table()
    s <- s %>% back()}
```

The problem is that I get this error: **No links have text 'Matemáticas'**.
I believe the problem is related with the text accent mark, because the first two links go through with no problem.

This may be a very basic question but I didn't find any info on this particular error.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please don't scrape these pages to build an e-mail spam list or an e-mail directory that's unaffiliated with that institution. When all salient info I see is names and e-mail addresses I get highly suspicious of intent.

Comment: That's not my intention. I study in that university and thats why I choosed that webpage as an example to scrape.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, as you suspect, with the special character (the accented a).  You can see how R views the link names with this code:

```
library(rvest)
top_url = "http://fccee.uvigo.es/es/profesorado.html"
page = read_html(top_url)
links = page %>% html_nodes("a") %>% html_text()
links
#> ...
#> [44] "MatemÃ¡ticas"
#> ...
```

This ends up being a complicated encoding issue which I can't figure out how to deal with.  So, instead, here's an alternate way to get your data.

```
library(rvest)
top_url = "http://fccee.uvigo.es/es/profesorado.html"
page = read_html(top_url)
links = page %>% 
  html_nodes(".listado_fccee li a") %>% 
  html_attr("href")
datos <- list()
for(i in links){
  datos[[length(datos)+1]] <- i %>% 
  paste0("http://fccee.uvigo.es",.) %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes(".lista_fccee") %>% 
  html_table()
}
```

Instead of using a session, you read in the first page, extract all the links from the div class `listado_fccee` which has the department links.  You then read each link and fetch the table as you did before, adding them to your list.