# rvest: cannot make follow_link() or jump_to move to an unordered list of links

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am scraping a website
url <- "https://www.rsaconference.com/usa/expo-and-sponsors"

This website has links to alphabets i.e. A B C D .... Z. Here is the html code copied from the website. If I want to follow a link say for letter 'B' or 'L' what is the best way using rvest package?

```
        <ul class="search-a-z" data-field-id="search__filter-letter">
        <li class="search-a-z__item"><a class="link link--default search-a-z__filter search-a-z__filter--disabled" href="#search-a-z" title="Filter results by  "> </a></li>
        <li class="search-a-z__item"><a class="link link--default search-a-z__filter " href="#search-a-z" title="Filter results by #">#</a></li>
        <li class="search-a-z__item"><a class="link link--default search-a-z__filter " href="#search-a-z" title="Filter results by A">A</a></li>
        <li class="search-a-z__item"><a class="link link--default search-a-z__filter " href="#search-a-z" title="Filter results by B">B</a></li>
        <li class="search-a-z__item"><a class="link link--default search-a-z__filter " href="#search-a-z" title="Filter results by C">C</a></li>
        <li class="search-a-z__item"><a class="link link--default search-a-z__filter " href="#search-a-z" title="Filter results by D">D</a></li>
        <li class="search-a-z__item"><a class="link link--default search-a-z__filter " href="#search-a-z" title="Filter results by E">E</a></li>
        <li class="search-a-z__item"><a class="link link--default search-a-z__filter " href="#search-a-z" title="Filter results by F">F</a></li>
        <li class="search-a-z__item"><a class="link link--default search-a-z__filter " href="#search-a-z" title="Filter results by G">G</a></li>
        <li class="search-a-z__item"><a class="link link--default search-a-z__filter " href="#search-a-z" title="Filter results by H">H</a></li>
        <li class="search-a-z__item"><a class="link link--default search-a-z__filter " href="#search-a-z" title="Filter results by I">I</a></li>
        <li class="search-a-z__item"><a class="link link--default search-a-z__filter " href="#search-a-z" title="Filter results by J">J</a></li>
        <li class="search-a-z__item"><a class="link link--default search-a-z__filter " href="#search-a-z" title="Filter results by K">K</a></li>
        <li class="search-a-z__item"><a class="link link--default search-a-z__filter " href="#search-a-z" title="Filter results by L">L</a></li>
        <li class="search-a-z__item"><a class="link link--default search-a-z__filter " href="#search-a-z" title="Filter results by M">M</a></li>
        <li class="search-a-z__item"><a class="link link--default search-a-z__filter " href="#search-a-z" title="Filter results by N">N</a></li>
        <li class="search-a-z__item"><a class="link link--default search-a-z__filter " href="#search-a-z" title="Filter results by O">O</a></li>
        <li class="search-a-z__item"><a class="link link--default search-a-z__filter search-a-z__filter--disabled" href="#search-a-z" title="Filter results by &#216;">&#216;</a></li>
        <li class="search-a-z__item"><a class="link link--default search-a-z__filter " href="#search-a-z" title="Filter results by P">P</a></li>
        <li class="search-a-z__item"><a class="link link--default search-a-z__filter " href="#search-a-z" title="Filter results by Q">Q</a></li>
        <li class="search-a-z__item"><a class="link link--default search-a-z__filter " href="#search-a-z" title="Filter results by R">R</a></li>
        <li class="search-a-z__item"><a class="link link--default search-a-z__filter " href="#search-a-z" title="Filter results by S">S</a></li>
        <li class="search-a-z__item"><a class="link link--default search-a-z__filter " href="#search-a-z" title="Filter results by T">T</a></li>
        <li class="search-a-z__item"><a class="link link--default search-a-z__filter " href="#search-a-z" title="Filter results by U">U</a></li>
        <li class="search-a-z__item"><a class="link link--default search-a-z__filter " href="#search-a-z" title="Filter results by V">V</a></li>
        <li class="search-a-z__item"><a class="link link--default search-a-z__filter " href="#search-a-z" title="Filter results by W">W</a></li>
        <li class="search-a-z__item"><a class="link link--default search-a-z__filter " href="#search-a-z" title="Filter results by X">X</a></li>
        <li class="search-a-z__item"><a class="link link--default search-a-z__filter " href="#search-a-z" title="Filter results by Y">Y</a></li>
        <li class="search-a-z__item"><a class="link link--default search-a-z__filter " href="#search-a-z" title="Filter results by Z">Z</a></li>
<li class="search-a-z__item search-a-z__item--clear">
    <a class="link link--default search-a-z__clear" href="#search-a-z" title="Clear filter">Clear Filter</a>
</li>
```

I tried the following but failed instantly:

```
s <- html_session(url)     
s %>% follow_link(i="Filter results by B")
```

> Error: No links have text 'Filter results by B'

I also tried,

```
s %>% html_node(".search-a-z__item:nth-child(4)") %>% follow_link()
```

> Error in follow_link(.) : is.session(x) is not TRUE

My objective is to loop through each of the A to Z links and scrape company names from each page.

I have searched many stackoverflow questions e.g. [Looping through a list of webpages with rvest follow_link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53648287/looping-through-a-list-of-webpages-with-rvest-follow-link) and 
[How to scrape this links with follow_link in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46801048/how-to-scrape-this-links-with-follow-link-in-r)
 but can't get my head around this.

Comment: the problem is that those links are not actual links to other pages, but just filters passed to some javascript. Honestly, if it is just this page, I'd keep scrolling to the bottom in the browser until it loads all ~650 items, than use the "save as" function from your browser, and voilà, you got a nice, locally stored html you can process with rvest with all data you need, you'll be done in 5 minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click on each letter on the page, the javascript sends an xhr POST request to a different url on the server, and encodes the request as a nested JSON. The bad news is that you will need to do the same to scrape the data. The good news is that you can get all the data in one gulp if you write the request properly.

You're going to need the Rcurl or httr package to give you this level of control over the http requests.

```r
# We'll use httr and tidyverse
library(tidyverse)
library(httr)

# This is the actual url that sends the JSON data
url <- "https://www.rsaconference.com/api/Search/FilteredSearch"

# These are the parameters we want to post. Note I have left the searchFilterLetter
# field blank so it sends us everything.
params <- list(defaultFilterContentType = "Exhibitor",
               searchInput = "",
               searchFilterLetter = "",
               exhibitorLocation = "none",
               exhibitorType = "none",
               filterTopicsTypeahead = "",
               filterTopics = "",
               searchSort = "alpha",
               filterRegion = "USA",
               filterConferenceYear = "2020")

# A complicating factor is that the above parsmeters are wrapped inside another
# parameter called formDsta, along with two other parameters. Note I want all
# exhibitors so I set resultsPerPage to 1000
body <- list(page = 1, resultsPerPage = 1000, formData = params)

# Now we post the form to the url and read the parsed JSON response.
# I have selected two fields from the resulting list.
POST(url, body = body, encode = "json")                     %>%
content("parsed")                                           %>%
`[[`("results")                                             %>%
lapply(function(x) data.frame(name = x$title, url = x$url)) %>%
{do.call("rbind", .)}                                       %>%
as_tibble                                                    ->
all_exhibitors
```

And here are your results...

```r
print(all_exhibitors)
#> # A tibble: 635 x 2
#>    name                     url                                                 
#>    <fct>                    <fct>                                               
#>  1 1TOUCH.io                /usa/expo-and-sponsors/1touchio                     
#>  2 360 Group                /usa/expo-and-sponsors/360-security-group           
#>  3 Abnormal Security        /usa/expo-and-sponsors/abnormal-security-corporation
#>  4 Acalvio Technologies     /usa/expo-and-sponsors/acalvio-technologies         
#>  5 Accedian                 /usa/expo-and-sponsors/accedian-networks            
#>  6 achelos GmbH             /usa/expo-and-sponsors/achelos-gmbh                 
#>  7 ACID Technologies        /usa/expo-and-sponsors/acid-technologies            
#>  8 Active Defense Institute /usa/expo-and-sponsors/active-defense-institute-ltd 
#>  9 Acunetix                 /usa/expo-and-sponsors/acunetix                     
#> 10 Adaptiva                 /usa/expo-and-sponsors/adaptiva                     
#> # ... with 625 more rows
```

Comment: Fantastic. Could you please @allan advise where do I find the list of `params` and how did you figure the actual url that responds with json data?

Comment: @Lazarus what I did was open a browser window and hit F12 so that the developer panel appeared. Then I navigated to the url of interest and cleared the console on the developer panel. Then I clicked on one of the letters and watched to see if the page made any http requests. I then looked at the requests to see which ones contained a response that held the data of interest. Once I found it, I looked to see what kind of request it was, whether any special cookies were needed, and how the request query was encoded. Then I replicated the request in R using my favourite http package.